# Windows 10 Pro to Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

Is it possible to install windows server 2016 over windows 10 Pro?

I have a workstation which has windows 10 pro installed. I need more that one person remoting in at the same time. Basically I need only Remote App support, and need a server os for the licensing. I'd rather not do a clean install.

Thanks

Comment: How do you suppose that you are going to get Windows Server 2016 on the machine without doing a clean installation of it?

Comment: When upgrading a Windows 7 machine to windows 10, I can keep all files and programs, and do an in place installation. My question was if that is possible with Windows server or is the architecture different and I need to format and install a fresh copy of Windows.

Comment: “My question was if that is possible with Windows server” - No;  “is it a architecture different“ - No;  “I need to format and install a fresh copy of Windows” - Yes;  Bottom Line: **it is not possible to upgrade Windows to Windows Server**